# If $f$ grows slower than exponentially, then $u$ does also.

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Let $X=\mathbb R^n$ and $A \in \mathcal L(X)$. Consider the differential equation $$u'(t)+Au(t)=f(t)$$ for $t>0$ where $f$ is a continuous function which doesn"t grow faster than exponentially, i.e. there are constants $M>0$, $t_o>0$ and $a>0$ such that $$|f(t)| \leq Me^{at}$$ for $t \geq t_o$

How can I show that no solution of the differential equation grows faster than exponentially, i.e. for every solution $u$ there are constants $K>0$ and $b>0$ such that $$|u(t)| \leq Ke^{bt}$$ for $t \geq t_o?$

Comment: Apply the integrating factor $e^{At}$.

Comment: Ok thank you, will have a read about integrating factors later on!

Comment: I don't really get what I want. Can you give me a short simple example please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One gets that
$$
\frac{d}{dt}e^{tA}y(t)=e^{tA}(y'(t)+Ay(t))=e^{tA}f(t)
$$
As $f$ is exponentially bounded, so is the new right side 
$$
\|e^{tA}f(t)\|\le\|e^{tA}\|·\|f(t)\|\le e^{t\|A\|}·Me^{at}
$$
From which
$$
\|e^{tA}y(t)\|\le\|y(0)\|+M\frac{e^{(a+\|A\|)t}-1}{a+\|A\|}
$$
and finally
$$
\|y(t)\|\le\|e^{-tA}\|·\|e^{tA}y(t)\|\le \|y(0)\|e^{t\|A\|}+\frac{M}{a+\|A\|}e^{(a+2\|A\|)t}
$$
which is an exponential bound for the solution.

Comment: Ok thank you. Where do you get the $y(0)$ from though?

Comment: From the fundamental  theorem of calculus. $e^{tA}y(t)-e^{0·A}y(0)=\int_0^t e^{sA}f(s)ds$.